# How to compile file sass to file css in one the main file css on the vuejs project

Tags: css, vue.js, sass

I am  setup the project of the vuejs on of the my goals in the end of the project is to compile files scss which  is the main file with name style.scss- from input to output in the file main file style.css to Load in the vuejs.
Also all files .scss should include with @importfor examples: @import "variables";and so on
in the main file  style.scss.
I read about it.[enter link description here](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/css.html#pre-processors)
My project is as in the picture below.
Any idea how to sole it?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: If you have a proper Webpack/Vite configuration, that one should be done for you once you bundle your project for production. Try to search how to make such setup.

Answer (score 0):

My dear friend, if I have understood your meaning correctly, I would like to try to offer you some solutions.

In order to use SCSS in a project and compile it automatically in the background, we can do the following [steps](https://mishkaorakzai.medium.com/how-to-add-and-compile-scss-to-run-automatically-in-the-background-on-an-existing-node-js-project-f0172141ae47):

**1. Install node-sass**

To get the compiler, we’re going to install the node-sass package.

Go to your terminal, navigate to the project folder and type in the following:

```
npm i node-sass
```

**2. Create an SCSS folder**

Create a new folder called scss in your project. After doing so, copy and paste all the CSS files from your css (or stylesheets) folder to your new scss folder.

[image]

Rename the extensions on all the newly pasted css files with .scss

You should end up with a scss folder which looks exactly like your css folder but with the files ending with .scss.

**3. Add a script in package.json**

In your package.json file, locate scripts and add the following piece of code inside it:

```
"scss": "node-sass --watch scss -o css"
```

If your css folder is named something other than css, then replace the word css with the folder name.

Similarly, if your scss folder is named something other scss, then replace scss with the correct folder name.

Setting context in the overall package.json file, the script will be placed like this:

```
{
   “name”: “example-project”,
   “version”: “0.4.2”,
   “scripts”: {
      “start”: “node ./bin/www”,
      “scss”: “node-sass — watch scss -o css”
},
   "dependencies": {
      "express": "~4.16.0",
      "express-favicon": "^2.0.1",
   }
}
```

**4. Run the compiler**

Get back into terminal and run the following commandL

```
npm run scss
```

Now you’ll notice any changes you make in your scss files will automatically be reflected in the css files.

if you have any new idea about Compile SASS to CSS you can check another steps with [this link](https://www.joomlart.com/documentation/t4-framework/compile-sass-to-css).